# vba download and save in C:\user

Tags: excel, vba, download

I want excel, using VBA, to download a file from the internet.  This file is a database with information about list of employees.  I want the file saved in C:\Users\"name of user"\FCMMIS\

This is the step-by-step process that I want to achieve:

1. Excel using VBA, downloads a file from a specified web address.
2. **The downloaded file is saved in C:\Users\"name of user"\FCMMIS**
3. Excel links with the downloaded database via VBA to get data that may be required.

As another note, the excel file in question will be used by different people with laptops.  I am not sure if saving the file in the "User" folder is possible or should there needs to be permissions to be given in order to allow a save.

I know that there are better solutions to this like writing a full application but due to the requirement, I am stuck with excel and VBA.

EDIT (to be done after along with part 3):

3.1: Once the database is downloaded, then the excel file gets records from the employee table and prints them in a new worksheet in the same excel file.

3.2: The printed data is then used for various functions in the worksheet.

However, I am in a debate whether is it much efficient to just manipulate the data in the database itself or have it work from the created worksheet.

Comment: a)  what have you tried so far? b) How do you think we can possibly help on part 3 - there is no scope?

Comment: Thanks for the reply brettdj.  I have a basic idea of what I want to do with part 3:

3.1: Once the database is downloaded, then the excel file gets records from the employee table and prints them in a new worksheet in the same excel file.

3.2: The printed data is then used for various functions in the worksheet.

However, I am in a debate whether is it much efficient to just manipulate the data in the database itself or have it work from the created worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is sourced from [an article by Matt Vidas](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=799)

And waiting for your answer to Point 3, no scope?

```
Function Download_File(ByVal vWebFile As String, ByVal vLocalFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte

    'You can also set a ref. to Microsoft XML, and Dim oXMLHTTP as MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False 'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.Send 'send request

    'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array

    'Create local file and save results to it
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF

    'Clear memory
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function



Sub Testing()
    Download_File "http://example.org/yourDataBaseFile", "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\yourDataBaseFile"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Larry as well as brettdj for the reminder regarding part 3.

There might be an instance that the excel file will be run on a Windows XP machine with Office 97-2003 installed since some of the supervisors will use their personal computers rather than the one provided by the company.

What worries me is the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object.  Is this native or for lack of better term included with the installation of Office 2010 only?

Comment: @SanchoAlmeda 
To my underlying, As long as the user has IE6 or above
MSXML2.XMLHTTP object comes along. 

For point3, assuming your table size isn't that huge, then maybe you can export some table as csv file or excel file. Then you can easily download and load them into a excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

If the file in question is an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) workbook you could do this:

```
With Workbooks.Open("http://example.org/yourfile.xls")
    .SaveAs "C:\Users\example\yourfile.xls"
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Hi, I think you can change the second line into 
        .SaveAs "C:\Users\" & environ("username") & "\yourfile.xls"

Comment: Thanks tyomitch for the suggestion and Larry for the follow-thru with save path.

This could be an alternative that I will look at since it can accomplish the same output.  But since there might be too many information that I need and that those information are stored into a database by another system, I believe that getting a database file would be a good choice at the moment.