# VB6: Downloading files from Sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint, https, download, vb6, office365

My work just migrated us from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 365. I've made many tools that download files directly from the Sharepoint directories. Apparently my download code (and any other code to download an online file) no longer works. Here's the code I've used in the past:

```
Function Download_File(ByVal vWebFile As String, ByVal vLocalFile As String, lFilesize As Long) As Boolean
'   Code taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815142/vba-download-and-save-in-c-user
'   on 2013-06-19
    Dim strHeader As Variant
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte

    On Error Resume Next

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 1"
    'You can also set a ref. to Microsoft XML, and Dim oXMLHTTP as MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"): Me.Repaint: Debug.Print Time$: DoEvents
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False: Me.Repaint: Debug.Print Time$: DoEvents 'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.sEnd: Me.Repaint: Debug.Print Time$: DoEvents 'send request

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 2"
    'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 3"
    strHeader = oXMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders
    If InStr(1, strHeader, "Content-Length:") > 1 Then
        lFilesize = CLng(Mid(strHeader, InStr(1, strHeader, "Content-Length:") + 16, InStr(1, strHeader, "Content-Type:") - (InStr(1, strHeader, "Content-Length:") + 16)))
    End If

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 4"
    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 5"
    'Create local file and save results to it
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage 6"
    'Clear memory
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing

Debug.Print "Download_File: Stage End"

End Function
```

The issue is that I'm able to download *a* file, it's just not the right size. Maybe it's just a container that has the correct file name? One possible issue is that we're now using Secure HTTP while before it was standard HTTP.

Using the Sharepoint-provided "Download Link" does not work either. Is this a 365 issue or an https issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked inside the file to see if it contains a server error message

Comment: Good advice! I opened it in CodeLobster and found it's actually an HTML! I added ".html" to the filename and opened with Chrome. It opens the file in "PowerPoint Online". So when I want to download it, it's actually giving me an html file to open the file online.

This at least helps hone in on the issue. I need to find a way to reliably download a local copy of the file from Sharepoint 365. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using WebDAV protocol?

Comment: Hi Bob, I hadn't tried the WebDAV protocol. I've done some searching on it since you made this comment and haven't found much on how to set it up or use it in vb6. Do you have a reference I can use to get more info?