# VBA download file onclick

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I need guidance on how to download an excel file from a webpage.

The following procedure is as followed :

1. OPEN internet explorer and navigate to a site.
2. login to the site with the credentials and navigate to a page
3. input the account field as well as the start and end dates. It will then click search
4. click on the excel image to download the excel file or some other method ?????

**I am having trouble with step 4. I have tried two methods.**

A. Download file through Href. The file downloads but there is an error for the filetype.(Also the actual direct link to download the file is not on the html DOM)
inspect element)

B. Try using send keys to download. It will work for the first account but as I loop back to step three it will not input the account or dates or click search.

Here is images of the HTML DOM

Excel Download button:
[image: Excel Download button]

HTML DOM:
[image: HTML DOM]

Here is my code:

```
 'Download  file function
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
            ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
            ByVal szURL As String, _
            ByVal szFilename As String, _
            ByVal dwreserved As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
            
            'IE declare
            Public htmlbuttons As IHTMLElementCollection
            Public htmlbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
            Public HTMLINPUT As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
            Public HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            Public IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
            
            
            Sub PrimeDownload()
    
    Dim FileUrl,DestinationFile as string
    
    'copy shortcut of excel button - sameweblink as current webpage but with a #
    FileUrl = "https://www.xxxxxx.com/pbdirect2/report/sdcashrecon_report.action#"
    
    DestinationFile = "C:\Users\347505083\Documents\test\" & "test1.xls"
            
            IE.Visible = True
            IE.Navigate  "Navigatives to Site"
            
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop
            
           Set HTMLDOC = IE.Document
                
            
            
            ' Login to Acct
            HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_name").Value = "Username"
            HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_password").Value = "Password"
            
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            
            'Click login
            HTMLDOC.getElementById("sign-in-button").Click
            
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop
            
            
            
            'NAVI to Reporting > Balances > SD Cash Reconcilation
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
             IE.Navigate "Navigate to page"
            
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop
                
            'Account List
            Dim accounts As Variant
            Dim account As Variant
            accounts = Array("475-80580 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY", "475-80581 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY MRGN", "475-80582 - CCL ALTERNATIVE GLOBAL EQUITY", "475-80583 - CCL ALTERNATIVE GLOBAL EQUITY MRGN", "475-80584 - CCL ALTERNATIVE INCOME FUND", "475-80585 - CCL ALTERNATIVE INCOME FUND MRGN", _
            "475-85000 - CCL MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE FUND", "475-85001 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND 1", "475-85002 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND", "475-85003 - CCL US Q MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85004 - CCL Q CANADIAN EQUITY 120/20 FUND", "475-85005 - CCL Q EQUITY EXTENSION FUND" _
            , "475-85007 - CC & L Q 120/20 FUND II", "475-85008 - CCL US Q MKT NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85009 - CCL US Q MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85016 - CC & L ASF (Q US)", "475-85017 - CC & L ASF (Q Canada)", "475-85018 - CC & L ASF (Fundamental)", "475-85019 - CC & L ASF (Fixed Income)" _
            , "475-85029 - CC & L ASF (Collateral)", "475-85030 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (QUANT)", "475-85031 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (FNDMTL)", "475-85032 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (FI)", "475-85036 - CCL FIXED INC ABSOLUTE RETURN", "475-85037 - CCL Q US EQUITY EXTENSION FD", "475-85036 - CCL FIXED INC ABSOLUTE RETURN" _
            , "475-85039 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND II", "475-85040 - CCL Q 130/30 FUND II")
          
          
        'Loop through accounts
         For Each account In accounts
            
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        
            'Enter Account
            HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input")(0).Value = account
            
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
             
             'Enter to Date
            HTMLDOC.getElementById("toDate").Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            
            'Enter from date
            If Weekday(myDate, vbMonday) > 5 = True Then
                HTMLDOC.getElementById("fromDate").Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                Else
                    HTMLDOC.getElementById("fromDate").Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                End If
            
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        
            'Click Search
            HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("pb2Button")(0).Click
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop 
     **Method A**  
        urldownloadtofile(0, fileurl, destinationfile, 0, 0)
    
    **Method B**
            'Click on excel download button
            HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")(52).Click
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
            
           'Sendkey to save from the save dialog box
            SendKeys ("%s")
           
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            IE.Navigate ' Navigate back to account search page
           
         Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
                Loop
            
            Next account
end sub
```

Comment: use execScript method of `ie.document.parentWindow` to call the `onclick` function with the arguments shown in the DOM. Or, try `ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='downloadReport(3, \'excel\']);']").click`

Comment: @QHarr thank you for replying ! I believe the script you mention will only activate the savedialog box, but I can complete this with the : HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")(52).Click line    I was wondering how would I save it to the appropriate file path after ?

Comment: Windows APIs e.g. FindWindow

Comment: If you know the url of the excel file, you can directly use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` to download the file to the folder you want. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815142/vba-download-and-save-in-c-user) for the detailed code. If you don't know the url of the excel file, you can use `FindWindow` which QHarr suggested. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133068/how-to-press-save-on-internet-explorer-popup) about how to use `FindWindow`.

Comment: thanks Yu zhhou.  Unfortunately the MSXML2.XMLHTTP method would not work since this is no direct href link to the download the file. I've been researching in the findwindow method and found this

Answer (score 0):

```
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" _
                                      Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, _
                                      ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                                               ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long) As LongPtr
    
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr
    
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    
    
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    
    
    
        Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
        Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
        Public Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
        Public Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE
    
        Public Const VK_KEYDOWN = &H0
        Public Const VK_KEYUP = &H2
        Public Const VK_CONTROL = &H11
    
    
    
    
    
    'Download  file function
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFilename As String, _
    ByVal dwreserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    
    
    
    
    'IE declare
    Public htmlbuttons As IHTMLElementCollection
    Public htmlbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Public HTMLINPUT As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Public HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Public ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    
    
    
    Sub PrimeDownload()
    
    
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://waf.rbccm.com/auth/Login?GAREASONCODE=-1&GARESOURCEID=204Ext&GAURI=https://www.rbccm.com/service/core/application.htm&Reason=-1&APPID=204Ext&URI=https://www.rbccm.com/service/core/application.htm"
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
        
    Set HTMLDOC = ie.Document
    
    ' Login to Acct
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_name").Value = "Username"
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_password").Value = "Password"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    'Click login
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("sign-in-button").Click
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
    
    
    'NAVI to Reporting > Balances > SD Cash Reconcilation
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ie.Navigate "https://www.rbccm.com/pbdirect2/report/sdcashrecon_report.action"
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        
    
    Dim accounts As Variant
    Dim account As Variant
    accounts = Array("475-80580 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY", "475-80581 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY MRGN")
    'accounts = Array("475-80580 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY", "475-80581 - CCL ALTERNATIVE CDN EQUITY MRGN", "475-80582 - CCL ALTERNATIVE GLOBAL EQUITY", "475-80583 - CCL ALTERNATIVE GLOBAL EQUITY MRGN", "475-80584 - CCL ALTERNATIVE INCOME FUND", "475-80585 - CCL ALTERNATIVE INCOME FUND MRGN", _
    "475-85000 - CCL MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE FUND", "475-85001 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND 1", "475-85002 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND", "475-85003 - CCL US Q MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85004 - CCL Q CANADIAN EQUITY 120/20 FUND", "475-85005 - CCL Q EQUITY EXTENSION FUND" _
    , "475-85007 - CC & L Q 120/20 FUND II", "475-85008 - CCL US Q MKT NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85009 - CCL US Q MARKET NEUTRAL ONSHORE II", "475-85016 - CC & L ASF (Q US)", "475-85017 - CC & L ASF (Q Canada)", "475-85018 - CC & L ASF (Fundamental)", "475-85019 - CC & L ASF (Fixed Income)" _
    , "475-85029 - CC & L ASF (Collateral)", "475-85030 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (QUANT)", "475-85031 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (FNDMTL)", "475-85032 - CCL MULTI-STRATEGY FUND (FI)", "475-85036 - CCL FIXED INC ABSOLUTE RETURN", "475-85037 - CCL Q US EQUITY EXTENSION FD", "475-85036 - CCL FIXED INC ABSOLUTE RETURN" _
    , "475-85039 - CCL Q MARKET NEUTRAL FUND II", "475-85040 - CCL Q 130/30 FUND II")
    
    
    
    
    For Each account In accounts
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    'Enter Account
    HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input")(0).Value = account
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
     
     'Enter to Date
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("toDate").Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    'Enter from date
    If Weekday(myDate, vbMonday) > 5 = True Then
        HTMLDOC.getElementById("fromDate").Value = Format(Date - 3, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    'Click Search
    HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("pb2Button")(0).Click
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    'Clicks on the excel save button
    HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")(52).Click
    
    'This will grab the save notifcation bar and save the document
    timeout = Now + TimeValue("00:00:4")
    Dim o As IUIAutomation
        Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))
        Set o = New CUIAutomation
        Dim h As Long
        h = ie.hWnd
        'find notification bar
        h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
        If h = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
        'find save button
        Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
        Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
        Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
        Do Until Not Button Is Nothing
            Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
            Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
        Loop
    
        'click save
        Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
        Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        InvokePattern.Invoke
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    
    ' It will navigate back to this screen but it will not enter the fields from the beginning of the loop need to gain control on the main IE window
    ie.Navigate "https://www.rbccm.com/pbdirect2/report/sdcashrecon_report.action"
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
    Next account


end sub
```

I have following vba references:
[VBA REFERENCES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8a3w.png)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.